# Get all apps listed in google play developer console page

Tags: php, curl, google-play

I want to get all apps data that are listing in developer console page. for this purpose I analyze the ajax request from firebug console.
1) A GET to the authentication page(https://play.google.com/apps/publish/),  gather cookies and other information

2) A POST using those values + my login credentials, to get the xsrftoken and developersconsoleaccounts variables

3) Then  make POST requests https://play.google.com/apps/publish/insights?dev_acc=devID and set post var xsrftoken, method, params

it return some garbage data

> ‹¬TÉnÛ0ý•I‚qZ²’À‰6èv)Ú¢H=”8’S¤JÒ–Ã@£¿×/))ÛÙŠº\DhH½šI^}xyóåãkhl+òÔ?APYg(ó´EK¡l¨6h³¹­ÈÕ®&i‹Ù‚cß)m¡TÒ¢´Ù!—Ür*ˆ)©Àlr­«´óö¡Ðsf›Œá‚—H†—Ã<µÜ
>   Ì_k­4\„pò^Yx£æ’&i°ÝO]¹åtÝR]s‡IGã²ŽÃ—}V*†ëÊi‰'—Ý2ˆ¢n T;=g†JCj^
>   '×-gµöñQUUI©„ÒñQE÷˜bS(¶ÚÓMÎ­‚0iér+=>¿»eâL’yÝ8â+_Øcœ»a€:…¸GÜs-N‚
>   ïûq­T-p\ª6à-­ÑèÓ0V…²ãNÖ#˜„á18(ŠhìÚ=Ñyz¢n/x2Ø}‰Z
>   ®„êã†3†rÃ¥YïLO§ÓÄâÒ†¥ÒÔr%c©$n(ð¶^J3Ô.â-2NÁ”Q•N‚˜NËhýÜ
>   ÇI¶rˆU]ü8»aï©p³9ªV˜‘ÿäÖ´·Ñ6§ûxö’•«§ºF‰ùàvr±ŽÖÿÄ}Ûègôà®+<†kó„´êŽló$Êß¸”~gŒôXÌ¸%Þà®Ç:¾DA†{£ÿî1Ù3>
>   Ãï0¾w½¿RÆM'è*æRp‰¤ªœ%»®¹tÿm²ý+&—®g6i°íõ”ñp–ÒŠbˆ5Ôh76(4«ìõnRtTúï<ó0ˆ
>   Šìíp(wðî€[hžvyZänèŒÓ
>   È!u‘ß4ÔþøöÝ¸La`u{¾îÎÞ4¿ÎÑXdðùÓ;è©qqX¨¼ww#`nÀÍ×qãçxB@0“ªßCÎaþÿÿ™èYR…

but when I analysis in firbug this url return json obj that contain  all information of user apps

In my case, it is returning the garbage value instead of the user array.

Comment: What'S the question here?

Comment: Can you post the JSON object that you see in firebug in a standard browser?  Is it possible the Json object is encoded?

Comment: Did you find your own solution?  Care to share it?

Comment: I not find any solution still working on it  .its give me this obj {"result":{"1":[{"2":1,"3":{"1":{"1":"com.dl.ilmstream"}}},{"2":1,"3":{"1":{"1":"com.dl.nevermissfajr"}}}]},"xsrf":"AMtNNDHf-e1uzfmnrmAaJ9e-kwmSpFSW1w:1428164946804"}   in firebug

Comment: Looks to me like the response is compressed, it may be gzip. you should check your headers and possibly uncompress the response.
Here is a nice google explanation of how that all works:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/optimize-encoding-and-transfer

Comment: @farooq javeed What tutorial did you use for getting apps list from Google Play developer console?

Comment: April fools day? :) @farooqjaveed: as kapa89 asked, what documentation did you follow when started implementing this request schema? Could it be that the response you received is the expected one?

Comment: @kapa89  I not following any document just analyse ajax request in firebug and do it using curl php as I do normally to scraping data to other sites.

Comment: thanx @Beyerz this is in gzib compress and I uncompressed it. It is a 404 page html. but in fire bug this request response is json data.

Comment: @farooqjaveed Try to use url https://play.google.com/apps/publish/androidapps?dev_acc=devID, with content {"method":"fetch","params":{"2":1,"3":7},"xsrf":"XSRF_TOKEN"}, also use application/javascript as Content-type and add X-GWT-Permutation

Answer (score 0):

This is GZIPped compressed data. Appears to be a 404 page if you request it normally.

If you take your firebug request, and check out the headers that have been sent there - you'll have to add those headers to the request (most likely).

If you can replay the request with the proper headers it will probably return the right data. Allthough, im not sure if Google likes what you're doing... You might want to check up on that.

Comment: yes I have notice that some header has been set in the request like X-GWT-Module-Base, X-GWT-Permutation and permutaion is a some code I am unable to find this permutation code. for test I have set static code that I have found in firebug. but the response remain same 404 page.